# how to get value of stateparams in angular2?

Tags: angular

1. I am looking for stateparams in angular2. After searching on the angular2 official site i have found this.

`<a [router-link]="[ '/MyCmp', {myParam: 'value' } ]">`

but I can't understand how to get this value in the class or constructor of 
the class?

2. In the angular cheatsheet there are three methods of route config is there any

   `@RouteConfig([
     { path: '/:myParam', component: MyComponent, as: 'MyCmp' },
     { path: '/staticPath', component: ..., as: ...},
     { path: '/*wildCardParam', component: ..., as: ...}
   ])`

What is the difference between all these three: / and /: and /* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject `RouteParams` object into you constructor and then call the `get` function. This is the example in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html)

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]})
@RouteConfig([
 {path: '/user/:id', component: UserCmp, as: 'UserCmp'},
])
class AppCmp {}
@Component({ template: 'user: {{id}}' })
class UserCmp {
  id: string;
  constructor(params: RouteParams) {
    this.id = params.get('id');
  }
}
```

Regarding the three syntaxes, they seem self explanatory

```
 { path: '/:myParam', component: MyComponent, as: 'MyCmp' },  //Route with param
  { path: '/staticPath', component: ..., as: ...},            // Fixed route
  { path: '/*wildCardParam', component: ..., as: ...}        //match any route which ends with wildCardParam
```

**Update**: See this plunkr from the docs
http://plnkr.co/edit/iRUP8B5OUbxCWQ3AcIDm?p=preview

It is using `RouteParams`
One thing that i observed is that RouteParams are only available when the route itself has parameters defined else you get the below error.

Comment: i have used your code but got error named as "RouteParams" no found. should i have to import or inject from somewhere RouteParams ??

Comment: thnx for plnkr. but i have done with my problem using `@injectable` and `@inject`